# how to find source of dynamically loaded content

Tags: web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, fetch-api, web-storage

i want to scrape the entries in [this table](https://www.oregon.gov/oha/erd/pages/covid-19-news.aspx?wp5364=l:100,f:%7Bc:38877,o:%7Bt:2,o:%5B%22Weekly+Report%22%5D%7D%7D#data).  it is apparently populated by javascript after the page loads, so rather than scraping (with something like webdriver), i'd like to directly request the data from whatever service the javascript is talking to.

using chrome dev tools' network tab, i thought i'd narrowed it down to an `xhr POST` to `https://www.oregon.gov/oha/ERD/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery`, but the response shown doesn't look related, and none of the other network activity items seem to be either.

how do i track down exactly what request is populating the table?

Comment: It seems the actual data which populates that table is coming from `window.sessionStorage`.  So you might want to consider stepping through the code in browser devtools to see from where `window.sessionStorage` is getting populated with the data to begin with.

Comment: @sideshowbarker - thanks!  how did you figure that out?  i am trying to search for "storage" but can't find anything...  i don't have experience doing this kind of thing, how do i start stepping through the code?

Comment: From doing some very quick initial setting of breakpoints in devtools, I think the data may be getting into `window.sessionStorage` from some code that runs the `sessionStorage.setItem(e,e)` call in `https://apps.oregon.gov/Application/CDN/Assets/bundle.min.js?b=twitter-bootstrap,modernizr,jasny-bootstrap,js.cookie,outdated-browser,statewide-links,helpful-page-poll_an_bs,sp_2016`. I’ll make time to look a little further myself later, but in the meantime, if you walk the code more from there, setting some more breakpoints, you might be able to further isolate the source for the data.

Comment: As far as the debugging methodology, I’ll also try to make time to write up some details later. But in general if you’re not familiar with what info you can get from devtools, you can sometimes find out a lot just by poking around through the different tabs in there, and expanding things out til you find something interesting.

Comment: @sideshowbarker - thanks for your help!  i had never noticed the possibility to "break on subtree modifications" in the DOM.  having trouble navigating through so much minified js, so i'll look forward to your write up, but i'll keep looking in the meantime...  now i see why the javascript tag would be relevant :)

Comment: @sideshowbarker - as far as i can tell, the file/line you mention is part of some tests, according to the sourcemap.  i'm not seeing where the table relates to `sessionStorage`, but i don't know what i'm doing.  breaking on table modifications tends to get me into `_fnBuildAjax` in that file, but i'm not understanding the debugger.  i can click around in the call stack, but it seems to bring me to places dozens of lines higher in the file than the function named on the stack, and hovering over vars only sporadically shows me values.  what am i missing?

Comment: just seeing the `Application` tab and its `sessionStorage`, all the potential table rows are in fact stored in a key named `SoapClient_433965963`. once i clear `sessionStorage`, the `network` tab showed a `soap POST fetch` in `https://apps.oregon.gov/Application/CDN/Enterprise/scripts/sharepoint/oregon-sharepoint.js` that gets the data. server is `https://www.oregon.gov/oha/ERD/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`, body is `<GetListItems ...<listName>COVID-19 Updates...<viewName>{9AF7C82F-9B8B-48E6-B2F5-D75414F1B2FE}...` now have to read up on `fetch`, and it does look like there will be CORS problems...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223229/discussion-between-sideshowbarker-and-user1441998).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 introduced [web-storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage), which, like cookies, caches data locally.  this can prevent data requests after first loading a site.  in chrome dev tools, go to the `application` tab, and under `storage`, look for a key that has the data you want.  if it's there, you can clear the storage, refresh, and then you'll see either an `xhr` or `fetch` [1] request in the `network` tab that got the data.  you can right-click the request and copy it as a `curl` command to request the data directly with no scraping.  you might worry that the service will prevent access from outside its approved web front end, but `cors` can't stop you because it only applies to browsers.

[1] [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is an improved `xhr` available since 2015

thank you to @sideshowbarker for pointing me to `sessionStorage` and answering my `cors` questions.